# how to make this php code shorter?

Tags: php, loops

I have the following php code which works but it is too long and cumbersome for reading...

```
// get the row
 if ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] > 3 AND $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] < 7  ) {
   $row = "row1";
 }

 if ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] > 7 AND $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] < 12  ) {
   $row = "row2";
 }

 if ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] > 12 AND $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] < 17  ) {
   $row = "row3";
 }

 if ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] > 17 AND $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] < 22  ) {
   $row = "row4";
 }

 if ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] > 22 AND $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] < 27  ) {
   $row = "row5";
 }

 // get the columns
 if ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 3 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 8 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 13 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 18 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 23) {

   $col = "col1";
 }  

 if ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 4 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 9 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 14 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 19 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 24) {

   $col = "col2";
 }

 if ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 5 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 10 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 15 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 20 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 25) {

   $col = "col3";
 }

 if ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 6 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 11 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 16 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 21 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 26) {

   $col = "col4";
 }

 if ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 7 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 12 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 17 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 22 
     or $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 27) {

   $col = "col5";
 }
```

Now... I have to repeat this from ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] until ($taktArticle[0]['t1position11']

As you understand, code will become huge...Anyone have an idea how this code can be shortened?

Regards, John

Comment: Just wrap if to function and pass args it needs as argument.

Comment: Briefly says what it does?

Comment: It is an array which have different values, but the element position depend from the class. $row and $col variables are css classes.

Comment: There are gaps in there. Are you sure that there should be no row for 7,12 and so on?

Comment: +1 to @JakubKania. Furthermore, the $row1 is only based on 3 valid tokens (4, 5, 6), while others based on 4 (8, 9, 10, 11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create functions to clean up the code.  There are obvious patterns in your code, looking for those patterns and generalizing those patterns is a key requirement to cleaning up your code.  I'm sure a PHP guru could find a more concise way to accomplish this, but a basic example is something like:

```
function get_row($position) {
  $row_ranges = array(
    array(3, 7),
    array(7, 12),
    // etc
  );     

  foreach ($row_ranges as $row_index => $range) {
    if ($range[0] < $position && $position < $range[1]) {
       return sprtintf('row%s', $row_index + 1)
    }
  }

}
```

All the row ranges are kept in a centralized location inside of your function, and there are no more repeated conditionals

```
function get_column($value) {
  // looks like you are starting at 3 and have increments of 5 
  // 3, 8, 13, 18
  // you could loop through and calculate these, or hardcode them in
  //  use `in_array` to clean up the multiple or statements
  if (in_array($value, array(3, 8, 13, 18))) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did the trick as well as the answer of the Oli above. Combined, both solution provde nice short code...at least much shorter than it was.

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to make an array an look it up:

```
$rowtbl = array(4 => 1, 1, 1, 8 => 2, 2, 2, 2);
$row = 'row'.$rowtbl[$taktArticle[0]['t1position3']];
```

of course the array could get large but you can build something from array_merge and range.

Moreover it seems to me that you could do something like:

```
$row = ceil(($taktArticle[0]['t1position3']-3)/5);
$col = ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3']-3)%5;
```

You'd have to check the exact parameters for 3 and 5 (3 would be the starting points and 5 would be the number of cols per row.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand this...I will take a look and give it a try in a minute however.

Answer (score 1):

Good answer on the first part by Christoph already.

As for the columns, instead of multiple comparisons inside the IFs, use `in_array`.

> Now... I have to repeat this from ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] until ($taktArticle[0]['t1position11']

Your fault for choosing such a sub-optimal data structure.

Why is this data not organized as `$taktArticle[0]['t1position'][3]` to `$taktArticle[0]['t1position'][11]`, so that you could easily loop over the positions …?

(And if there’s analogues to `t1position`, so you have `t2position`, `t3position` etc. as well – then those should be organized in arrays too.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if(in_array($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'],array(7,12,17,22,27)))
```

In place of this type of statement

```
if ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 7 
OR $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 12 
OR $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 17 
OR $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 22 
OR $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 27)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the columns section, rather than joining several `OR` operators you could check whether your `$taktArticle[0]['t1position3']` value is present in an array.

Using PHP `in_array` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for example:

```
if(in_array($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'], [3, 8, 13, 18, 23])) {
    $col = "col1";
}
```

Although this is cleaner, you're still hard-coding all the values in this mapping, so the maintenance overhead will grow as you add new cases.

Answer (score 0):

There are patterns in there so you can use division instead of arrays:

```
$temp = $taktArticle[0]['t1position3']-2
if($temp%5 != 0){
  $row = "row".ceil(($taktArticle[0]['t1position3']-2)/5);
}
$col = "col".(($taktArticle[0]['t1position3']-2)%5);
```

Comment: Fixed. Now it will work. Though taken what answer got accepted I still think the gaps shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do like this

```
   if((((int)$taktArticle[0]['t1position3'])-7)%5==0||((int)$taktArticle[0]['t1position3'])-7)==0)
```

for this statement

```
   if ($taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 7 
   OR $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 12 
   OR $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 17 
   OR $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 22 
   OR $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'] == 27)
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is use boolean operators in switch to get row and recursive function to get col

```
//to get Row:
$m = $taktArticle[0]['t1position3'];
switch($m){
    case ($m>3 && $m< 7): $row = 'row1'; break;
    case ($m>7 && $m< 12): $row = 'row2'; break;
    case ($m>12 && $m< 17): $row = 'row3'; break;
    case ($m>17 && $m< 22): $row = 'row4'; break;
    case ($m>22 && $m< 27): $row = 'row5'; break;
}

//To get Col
function rootNum($num){
    return $num-5>0?rootNum($num-5):$num;
}
$n = rootNum($taktArticle[0]['t1position3']);
$col = 'col' . ($n -2);
```